# EchartJS - selected legend and display only what is selected

Tags: javascript, echarts

i have that : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ucp.png)

and when i want to click on one legend , i want this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e20KA.png)
but i have this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogdCI.png)

my question is : it's possible or not ?
I don't know if it's clear enough but I'll answer the question if needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `legendselectchanged` [event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.legendselectchanged) and use `dispatchAction` to execute [actions](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.legend) on the legend.

It was not clear to me what exact beaviour you want. I made a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-borderRadius&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQRjUC29xAvgDTHbU3QAJoVQkMoBgEYArAFJ6PMXwBmYBnIXF0wctWhrY9AG61IAYwCG2TWOYAPMAGUwATz4jYymE4gAvaoQATNKw3FqwAM7UfGaYdLAA2kgYLiABhlbWoQC6nIqRtBDUEYQJ4aJiKWkMIEU2laQWghAAriWJ9NIaXIYA7AAM8tn5YhZGwBCCADIWAEbRAPImpNgWBJ5WUSMkTKzObukVlbCzOoK0AEpNre0AzNLbYqek56QAwjg6DADEyn_1x2erwA6pMwAALQgADnC6DCx1W82wIlhJAi4OAAHdCMpNtRHiQQMAIkwoNAGGY9MxSOxjvDKojolMINBDqj0OisTi8aj6WJBBYwBZSuzkLAjFYWulAj1oBYWOl6FMLgBaACyjnooQJ6GSEuwUqCsvliuV6oAQirbv0tXzKnrJelJMaFQwzRqVRdHAAWKHSFUAEQAkgA5W2o3JiDjEXIcADcKBQLBcb3BFlIYAAdDAABT0PgCQRRGJgMxp6A0QQKTwtaCxMmwHMgdPyiIASiI6DMMAiOGomewwAoTZbLHbcbEAHpJ7BBxRYNQTPpxLOsABrWCC2BMCKRMCkFqxFqkajEbvQCJgWByhUIWDNxpjzM36gJ9DJ1PprPNCLN0vggBBetcyOKpFQLPRBAA7BsEcaJqFiWlQjbN9YA_NMM0zH8_zLIDIBA8JXGqQwIKEINoGWKI4JLJCOBQ4h0K_LCIF_QVcOA6Ac1AojwP4SDqIQsAAWvE1CBfTh6LouMgA) to showcase how it can be done. You can implement more complex logic using the `selected` object contained in `params`.

```js
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;


myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function (params) {
  console.log(params); // log event to look at its structure
  const name = params.name;
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendAllSelect'
  });
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendInverseSelect'
  });
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'legendSelect',
    name: name
  });
});


option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  legend: {
    top: '15%',
    left: '5%',
    orient: 'vertical',
    textStyle: { fontSize: 25 },
    selector: [{ type: 'all' }]
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['55%', '70%'],
      avoidLabelOverlap: false,
      itemStyle: {
        borderRadius: 35,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 8
      },
      label: {
        show: false,
        position: 'center'
      },
      labelLine: {
        show: false
      },
      data: [
        { value: 2, name: 'LR-MS' },
        { value: 2, name: 'LR-MB-30' },
        { value: 1, name: 'LR-MS-RS485-DIN' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```